# Embedded video viewing in Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, ios, google-chrome, video

**Problem**

I'm creating a website with embedded videos. I'm trying to ensure mobile browsing compatibility. I'm using the  tag as follows:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls id="video_player" preload="none" poster="poster.jpg" autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" />
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis" />
  <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" />                
</video>
```

The video plays in desktop browsers and iPhone/iPad devices iOS 8.4 and higher, but *not* iOS 7.1. The video also plays on an Android Tablet OS version 4.4.2 Chrome version 38.0.2125.114. However, the embedded video will *not* play on an Android phone OS version 5.0.2 Chrome version 43.0.2357.93.

On iOS 7.1 there is an error icon. On Android the length is always at 0:00 and once it tries to play the video it turns transparent.

I have tried using Javasript to manually call video.play() on a button click, with no luck on the Android 5.0.2 phone.

The mp4 video in question is encoded using Handbrake with settings:

> h.264 Profile: Baseline
>
> h.264 Level: 3.0
>
> Audio: AAC
>
> Web Optimized

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try it without the codecs specified in the tag?